# How can i implement google tracker in Any project in Android?

Tags: android

I download Project from below link it works great but How i implement in my Project?

Svn Link :- http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Any body help me for implementing google tracker full example?

Thanks.